# Why am I getting "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" here?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically title. I create a new fragment of a larger array and I get this error. I have to create a new fragemnt of a larger array to display it. (Think in Pokemon, where the map is the big array but the screen that is shown is the fragment of that map.) Here is the code.

Where the method is called:

```
    public void showWorldFragment(){
******ERROR WITH THIS LINE*********
        int[][] map = getWorldFragment(mapPack.map);
        if(map[0][0] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 0, 0, null);
        }
        if(map[0][0] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 0, 0, null);
        }
        if(map[1][0] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, canvasWidth/3, 0, null);
        }
        if(map[1][0] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, canvasWidth/3, 0, null);
        }
        if(map[2][0] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 2*(canvasWidth/3), 0, null);
        }
        if(map[2][0] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 2*(canvasWidth/3), 0, null);
        }
        if(map[0][1] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 0, canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[0][1] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 0, canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[1][1] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, canvasWidth/3, canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[1][1] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, canvasWidth/3, canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[2][1] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 2*(canvasWidth/3), canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[2][1] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 2*(canvasWidth/3), canvasHeight/3, null);
        }
        if(map[0][2] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 0, 2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }
        if(map[0][2] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 0, 2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }
        if(map[1][2] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, (canvasWidth/3), 2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }
        if(map[1][2] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, (canvasWidth/3),  2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }
        if(map[2][2] == 1){
            c.drawBitmap(balloon, 2*(canvasWidth/3), 2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }
        if(map[2][2] == 2){
            c.drawBitmap(archer, 2*(canvasWidth/3), 2*(canvasHeight/3), null);
        }

    }
```

Where the method is called:

```
    public int[][] getWorldFragment(int[][] map) {
        int centerX = x;
        int centerY = y;
        if(x == 0){
            centerX = 1;
        }
        if(x == map.length){
            centerX = map.length-1;
        }
        if(y == 0){
            centerY = 1;
        }
        if(y == map.length){
            centerY = map.length-1;
        }
        int[][] tempFragmentArray = new int[][]{
                {map[centerX-1][centerY-1], map[centerX][centerY-1], map[centerX + 1][centerY - 1]},
                {map[centerX-1][centerY], map[centerX][centerY], map[centerX + 1][centerY]},
                {map[centerX-1][centerY+1], map[centerX][centerY+1], map[centerX + 1][centerY + 1]},

        };
        return tempFragmentArray;

    }
```

The mapPack.map is a larger 5x5 array that just holds basic integer values. Does anyone have any idea as to why this happens?

Let me know if any more details are needed.

Thanks :)

Comment: Because it is out of bounds. Don't doubt. Find that *actual* size of the array  and the *actual* index. The exception message will indicate the latter, at least.

Comment: What line? Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: This is where using the debugger to debug your code is really the best place to start.

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: Debugger? Eew, No this is where doing test driven development is the best place to start.  Baring that debugging scaffolding.   Debugger only as a last resort.  Reading the stacktrace though is always a good idea.

Comment: @CandiedOrange My favorite is a debugger attached to a test ..

Comment: Any test that you need a debugger to help you with is not a good test.  And show the stack trace already!

Comment: @CandiedOrange To debug/fix the code to make such pass a test (or rather, to find out why it doesn't pass a test it should) of course; not an intrinsic part of checking the test. After the code is fixed to pass the test then the test holds it's own for regression against such contracts.

Comment: I used to code like that.  I'm glad I don't anymore.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I don't see a 'problem' with such .. attaching a debugger for isolating a problem (where the test fails) doesn't violate TDD or tests-first design, even though it may indicate that the tests (or contracts) could be more refined. Of course if a simple stack trace allows quick identification of the problem (and cause of such) without using a debugger, use that.

Comment: Look everyone has their thing but personally I take use of a debugger as a sign of one of three things:  Code that doing to much, A test that's doing to much, A developer who doesn't understand the basics of the language does and needs to be taught.  The debugger is like training wheels.  It's something you grow out of.

Comment: Do you test protected (I avoided using 'private') methods? Blackbox? Because there are some tasks that quite simply can't be broken up sufficiently without also bleeding details. A trivial example would be something like a non-recursive sort implementation.

Comment: You really should not write code like that, perhaps you could write a more sane way to figure out your points on the map instead of just always in/decrementing by one and assuming you won't get an index out of bounds exception... thats just asking for bad times.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - You have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @HotLicks this might very well be true.  But if that's all you have to say I'll continue to live in ignorance.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - After you've got another 10-20 years of experience under your belt you will see the error of your ways (assuming you don't become an manager and cause some poor programmers grief by doing buzzword management).

Comment: @HotLicks I doubt it since I'll likely be retired by then.  Been coding since I was 10 and have never stopped.  If you have something of substance to say spit it out.  This is just clutter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the inner exception is coming from this line:

```
 int[][] tempFragmentArray = new int[][]{
                 {map[centerX-1][centerY-1], map[centerX][centerY-1], map[centerX +      1][centerY - 1]},
                 {map[centerX-1][centerY], map[centerX][centerY], map[centerX + 1][centerY]},
                 {map[centerX-1][centerY+1], map[centerX][centerY+1], map[centerX +      1][centerY + 1]},

    };
```

The variable x and y look to be inner class members and probably they go to wrong index of your 2D map array.